# feeding row data to ag-grid vue component

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

In all the ag-grid-vue examples, data of rows are generated in the component's method of createRowData(), which is simple but not realistic.

I want to see an example in which row-data are provided to ag-grid vue component from the parent Vue instance.

If there's such information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way by using Veux. Here's an example.

Appication.

```
let gridRows = {
  state: {
    rowData: []
  },
  mutations: {
    push(state, rows) {
      while( 0 < rows.length ){
        state.rowData.unshift(rows.pop());
      }
    },
  getters: {
    rowData: state => {
      let rows = state.rowData;
      return state.rowData;
    }
  }
};
let store = new Vuex.Store(gridRows);
let app01 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(DynamicComponentExample)
});

let rowData = [];
for (var i=0; i < 15; i++) {
  rowData.unshift({
    row: "Row " + i,
    value: i,
    currency: i + Number(Math.random().toFixed(2))
  });
}

store.commit('push', rowData);
```

Component (modification to DynamicComponentExample.vue)

```
  data () {
    return {
      gridOptions: null,
      columnDefs: null
      //rowData: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rowData(){
      return this.$store.getters['rowData'];
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    ...
    //this.createRowData();
    this.initColumnDefs();
  },
```